# middle mouse key alternative

Tags: 3d-view, camera, shortcut

everything has been great with blender. just one problem at the moment i need sort of alternatives button for middle mouse (the mouse wheel) button for rotating, panning etc. everything that have anything to do with the mouse wheel click.

after quite a while using it, now it's a bit broken and sometimes not responding on my click. much appreciated if someone can list everything that use middle mouse wheel button, that i need to change to completely replace the middle wheel click with something else. and alternative key suggestion would be nice too. (bit troubled with this one)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can emulate 3 Button Mouse.

#### Blender 2.7

*File* > *User Preferences...* (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>)

#### Blender >= 2.8

*Edit* > *Preferences...*

In the *Input* tab, check "Emulate 3 Button Mouse".

Now, you can emulate the middle button by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> (Left Mouse Button).

Comment: This interferes with some select loop keyboard shortcuts however. Is this the only solution for changing the use of the middle mouse button?

Comment: Off the top of my head, there's no alternative solution.
If you are familiar with python, you can toggle this preference using this line of code: bpy.types.PreferencesInput.use_mouse_emulate_3_button = not bpy.types.PreferencesInput.use_mouse_emulate_3_button.

Comment: There is a solution now - there is 'OS Key' as an option in those same preferences. On MacOS it is the Command key.