# Program Wide Key replacement

Tags: shortcut

Is there a way to quickly replace the middle mouse button click with something like mouse button 5?

I looked around and found this [middle mouse key alternative](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119784/middle-mouse-key-alternative).
It would be nice if I could change the emulated: 3 Button Mouse from Alt + LMB to mouse button 5.

Is it possible to change a button or shortcut program wide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend an application like [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm), it allows you to assign any virtual key / shortcut to any mouse button (per program or globally), I use it to trigger some special Blender features (like Render Only) by mouse side buttons.

Comment: Works better than expected. Thank you so much. I thought I had to sit there and go through each instance of middle mouse button click and change it,